# Pandas: Efficient way to check if a value in column A is in a list of values in column B

Tags: python, list, pandas, contains

my initial dataframe looks like this

```
 A   | B
-----------------
 'a' | ['1', 'a', 'b']        
 '1' | ['2', '5', '6']   
 'd' | ['a', 'b', 'd']        
 'y' | ['x', '1', 'y']
```

and I want to check if 'a' is in the corresponding list in B: ['1', 'a', 'b']

I could do that by using the apply

```
df.apply(lambda row: row[['A']][0] in row[['B']][0], axis=1)
```

that gives me the expected result:

```
[True, False, True, True]
```

but on the real data I have (millions of rows) that is very heavy and takes ages.
Is there a more efficient way to do the same thing? 
for example using numpy elementwise operations or anything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you convert each column to sets, you can use `<` to compare pairwise subsets

```
a = d.A.apply(lambda x: set([x]))
b = d.B.apply(set)

a < b

0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Otherwise, you can use a list comprehension with `zip`

```
[a in b for a, b in zip(d.A.values.tolist(), d.B.values.tolist())]

[True, False, True, True]
```

---

***timing small data***

[image]

***timing large data***

[image]

Comment: I chose the list comprehension way, that is absolutely a huge time saver. thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you please explain the reason why this is so much faster? thanks