# How to see if members of list A are in list B with pandas apply

Tags: python, pandas, comparison, apply, pairwise

I am trying to see if elements of one list A are in another list B and on which index. I know that they are not a pandas structures. But there should be a way to use these list to get the result of the example. Correct me if I am wrong, I am even newer to pandas.

For example

```
A = ['hi', 'I', 'Am', 'A', 'Test']
B = ['Sara', 'bla', 'bar', 'I', 'python', 'Test', 'Bye', 'hi']
```

And then get a resulting list C

```
C = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Where 1 indicates occurences of elements from a, and 0 says no occurence, in list B.

Still new to python btw.
I saw the answer here,
[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553523/pandas-efficient-way-to-check-if-a-value-in-column-a-is-in-a-list-of-values-in)  but I do not know how to apply this to my situation. It suggests the pandas function apply.

The option I want to explore is the one where you use the function named apply. The example shows that it is much faster and I a using a big dataset.

Comment: What does this have to do with pandas? Is this homework? Those are lists, not Series OR dataframes. What are you expecting?

Comment: But `1` does not appear in `B`.. Shouldn't `C` be `C = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]`?

Comment: whatever.. `C = [int(x in B) for x in A]`

Comment: This is not homework.  @c
I am actually working with words, but it was easier to explain with numbers.

Comment: You answered one question, ignoring the other 2.

Comment: This is not homework.  @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, I only have lists. But the example actually works with dataframes. So, I do not know how to use a list in this apply function. 
I am actually working with words, but it was easier to explain with numbers. I am trying to see if words in a sentence occur in a dictionary. However, I do not want to loop through a dictionary with 300k words everytime I need to see if a word is in the dictionary. The resulting list needs to say dictionary index x contains word w.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, I do not want to do A[0] == B[0], A[1] == B[1], etc.. That is why I want to use pandas. I want to see if the 2 in A is somewhere in B and return the location in C

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, I pressed enter by accident

Comment: So, please provide a [mcve] with _actual_ pandas data structures, not lists.

Comment: @nappingkid I am **not** doing `A[0] == B[0], A[1] == B[1]` either.. I am doing membership testing. Did you even try the code I posted above?

Comment: Yes, but I do not want to use for loops. Did you see the example?  @Ev.Kounis I know how to do membership testing with loops. I am trying to optimise the method. I have more than 300k items in a dictionary.

Comment: @nappingkid What `dictionary` now?...

Comment: yeah but your example has nothing to do with pandas. I've already explained, those are lists, not pandas structures.

Comment: My question is, how do I use these lists in the pandas apply function as in the example?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ are you saying that it is not possible to convert lists to pandas structures to use in the example?

Comment: I mean, it is, but that was supposed to be for you to do :p

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I have been trying it for the last hour or so. I googled a ton before I posted my question.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis sorry, I do not mean the python dictionary. I mean an vector of unique words. This vector is used to look up words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for `isin` + `astype`:

```
B.isin(A).astype(int)

0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    1
6    0
7    1
dtype: int64
```

Where `A` and `B` are both series.

If you want to perform substring comparisons, you'll need a slightly different solution involving `str.findall`:

```
B.str.findall('|'.join(A), flags=re.I).str.len().clip(0, 1)

0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    0
5    1
6    0
7    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This is exactly what I mean. Thanks! @COLDSPEED